# How to download Net Core Runtime from the Internet using WIX

Tags: .net-core, wix, wix3

I need to check if the environment is not installed, the installer downloads the latest version from the Internet

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
What have you done already? I can't understand the link between the question and its title, can you be more specific?

Comment: @P.Ellul Hello. I created an installer for my application. But I need to check if the user has the environment installed, if there is no download it directly from the site Microsoft